# How to create a react native ios share extension app

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-ios, ios8-share-extension

I want my react-native app to be available for share from Whatsapp, Skype, Photos.. I tried using [react-native-share-extension](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share-extension) but it is only showing the extension in the Safari browser.

How to implement the sharing feature in applications other than Safari in react-native for iOS?

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642385/share-extension-react-native-expo/53110237#53110237

Comment: try this package(https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding this in info plist

```
<dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, [react-native-share-extension](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension) only allows the sharing of urls from browsers. There is some extra configuration to add if you want to tell the system to show your extension when sharing a url that you seem to have missed.

For iOS, you simply need to update the `Info.plist` file and add the following:

```
<key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

To confirm it's done correctly, this setting should then be displayed in XCode and allow a successful build:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because the default setup if this package is for sharing urls to your app.

You need to change/extend/rewrite `NSExtensionActivationRule` in `Config.plist` of your share extension and stay with react-native-share-extension package. Read more about this key [from author](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share-extension#on-ios-set-the-nsextensionactivationrule-key-in-your-infoplist) and in [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW8) directly.

So you can rewrite entirely rule to apply e.g. pdf files (as said in apple docs):

```
<key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
    <string>
        {extensionItems = ({
            attachments = ({
                registeredTypeIdentifiers = (
                    "com.adobe.pdf",
                    "public.file-url"
                );
            });
        })}
    </string>
</dict>
```

All keys for `NSExtensionActivationRule` could be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW2).