# How to get file from URI | Expo | React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, filesystems, expo

I have ejected project of the expo.

After changing **info.plist**, now I am able to get my app in the list of "open with app list" and actually able to open that file with my expo(React native app).

App.js

```
Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
  if (url) {
        console.log(url);
    }

}).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

this code is giving me this URL.

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7E55EB55-7C49-4C0C-B4CB-63AC4F49689E/Documents/Inbox/matters-3.csv
```

So, that means now I have URL of the email attachment, but How am I able to get the data of that csv string in my app?

So I am assuming, when I click open with my app. The URL that is passed into my app from the system is actually a copy of the document that is placed somewhere in our app’s directory.

But when I trying to access this file with Expo.FileSystem. readAsStringAsync it's giving me an error says, the file is not readable.

**is there anything to do with storage permission?**

Need Help....?

Comment: can you please expand on what you want to do with the data? By "get the data of that csv" you mean to you want to read the entire file and show the contents on the screen or..?

Comment: I want to use that CSV file as a string to give one of my functions to import data in app

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs but note you may have performance problems if the file is large

Comment: @vonovak any updates?

Comment: So, I found that it's still using exp:/// scheme instead of my custom scheme from app.json

Comment: Do you have any idea how to change it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs). This here should work and print out the contents of the CSV file to the console.

App.js

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
  if (url) {
    RNFS.readFile(url).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    }

}).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

Comment: but when I create a file with writeFile and try to read it. It's work fine.

Comment: Do I have to specify anything while downloading file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-native-fs as Carlo mentioned or [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob), I recommend rn-fetch-blob, to read a file u can check their documentation, it goes something like this

```
let data = '';
RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream( ...options).then((ifstream) => {
ifstream.open()
ifstream.onData((chunk) => {
  data += chunk
  // show progress ...%
})
ifstream.onError((err) => {
  console.log('oops', err)
})
ifstream.onEnd(() => {  
  consol.log('final data', data)
})
```

}))