# How can I share media from one app to another?

Tags: react-native, expo

Is it possible to share an image, or even basic text, from one app to an expo app?

For instance, if I click on an image on Whatsapp and click share, I want to see my app show up on the list of apps that I can select and share to. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Probably duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642385/share-extension-react-native-expo

Comment: In what way is that question related?